# Beginning Testing in Java with JUnit

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ to write some integration tests.

### Project Structure:

```
/src
  /main
    /java
      /com.myCompany
        /dir
          /email
  /test
    /com
```

Over time, I will be writing unit, integration, and performance tests. However, I’m confused about how I should structure my directories for testing. I also don’t understand how package naming relates to testing. For instance, I’ve created a basic test that looks like the following:

```
package com.myCompany.dir.email;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EmailTest extends TestCase {

    private final String username = “[testAccount]”;

    private final String password = “[testPassword]”;

    @Test
    public void thisAlwaysPasses() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I can’t even get that test to run. I get errors ranging from:

```
Error running All unit tests: Package not found in directory
```

to

```
No tests found.
```

Any insights are much appreciated.

Comment: It should be `test/**java**/com`, not just `test/com`

Comment: You generally want your test hierarchy to have the same structure as you main hierarchy, so test/java/com/mycompany.

Comment: I kind of understand that. However, what if I want unit, integration, and performance tests in different files?

Comment: Does your source really have smartquotes like that in it? Also, is the directory name *actually* `com.myCompany`?

Comment: we name our test types differently (*Test, *IntegrationTest) and keep them in the same directory tree.  Performance tests have their own project.  This is largely up to the build script designer, though, and depends in part on how your tests are run and who runs them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good idea to have your tests packages mirror the package structure of your classes under test. In your concrete case it should look like this:

```
/src
  /main
    /java
      /com
        /myCompany
          /dir
            /email
              MyClass.java
  /test
    /java
      /com
        /myCompany
          /dir
            /email
              MyClassTest.java
```

Regarding your part of the question about Unit-, Integration- and Performance-Tests. We usually follow either one of the following approaches (it kinda depends on the project size):

- Create completely separate projects for Integration-Tests (and Performance Tests). In there you place your Tests within an identical package hierachy.
- Simply place your Integration-Tests (and Performance Tests) in the same package as your Unit-Tests, but give them some common suffix (e.g. MyClassIntegrationTest.java)

Answer (score 0):

1. there's no need to extend TestCase--the rest of your code is probably fine.
2. assuming you're using Maven directory structures (you appear to be), be sure you created a folder structure for tests which looks like: src/test/java/com/myCompany/dir/email--your class needs to be in a folder which matches its package name,
3. the extra quote in "[test"Password"]; -- you need to remove or escape it.

I'm guessing that #1 is the cause of the exception you're currently seeing.